# How to download file using curl only after redirect?

Tags: batch-file, curl, redirect

I want to create a batch file that would download file from url https://someurl.com/file which redirects me to https://someurl.com/file/download/smth.txt. How can I do this without using anything other than batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-L, --location` parametr to follow rediects.

Example :
`curl "https://someurl.com/file" -L -o smth.txt`

Also you can use `--max-redirs <num>` parameter to limit the number of redirects.

More inforamtion about these parameters and other you can find on [curl.se](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html), [-L parameter](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L), [--max-redirs](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--max-redirs)